# PHP - time and filemtime issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the difference between the current time and the filemtime in PHP.

The time and filemtime seems to return correct values, since, when applied to the date function, these values print correct dates. The difference between the time() function and filemtime is 1 hour according to the date function. However when I'm trying to get the difference between the returned timestamp values, the difference is 215. For example, see below:

current time = 1339599628, the date() function shows   13-06-2012 16:06:28 00
file modif time = 1339599413, the date() function shows   13-06-2012 15:06:30 30

This seems to be correct, but I can't see how to check the difference in seconds between these dates, since 1 hours has 3600 seconds, but the difference is only 215.

Also, I tried the following timestamp values:
1339599599  = 13-06-2012 15:06:59 59
1339599600  = 13-06-2012 16:06:00 00

So, the first timestamp values was incremented by 1, but the date gives 1 hours difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you just hit the change from winter time to summer time? When that happens, the real time span is just one second, but we adjust our clocks to 1hour of difference

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a problem with timezone difference. Try to look at [gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) function.

Or better, before you get these timestamps, call `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help. For instance, try this one:
    echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s i', 1339599599).'<br>';//13-06-2012 15:06:59 59 
    echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s i', 1339599600).'<br>';//13-06-2012 16:06:00 00
When I increment the first timespamt by 1, the date is +1hour.

Also I tryed this one:
    $time = mktime(15, 30, 30, 6, 13, 12);
    echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s i', $time);
Thei should be 13-06-2012 15:30:30, but it gives: 13-06-2012 15:06:30 30.

Comment: @Andrei Have you tried to reset the timezone before you call both `time()` and `filemtime()` to get these stamps? You should get different numbers. In case of your `mktime()` - `gmmktime()` would also give you different results.

Comment: Ye, I tried to reset, but still the same.  
What I'm trying to do, is to remove all files that were not acessed in the last 25 minutes.  
I'm using the time() function to get the current time stamp and filemtime() to get the file mod time.  
As I understand, the following code should do the treak:  
if($fileModTime - $currentTime > 25*60) unlink($file);  
But this doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrei what configuration are you running? This [old bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40568) might be related.

Comment: It works on Win 7, but I tried on linux and doesn't work. Config: Apache  2.2.22, PHP 5.3.10, architecture: x86_64.

Comment: @Andrei I [did a test](http://pastebin.com/HZMLT7bW) using PHP CLI on my Linux machine. File `a` was freshly created. Please try to do the same and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case the time difference between time() and filemtime() was 51 seconds. I have no idea what causes this, but I did find a workaround. When a file is created I use `touch($file, time())`. Now the creation time of the created file is set "in sync" with time().

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question...
both time and filemtime returns timestamps.

biggestOne - smallestOne = diff in seconds.
There shouldn't be anything more to it.

Comment: It doesn't even matter what order you put them in the calculation - it is just  `$difference = abs($timeStamp1 - $timeStamp2);`

Comment: it does not matter as long as you use abs :)
The point is just to know what is problem really is...

Comment: The problems seems to be in the returned values. The difference between time() and filemtime() is 215. But when applied to the data function, these values give 1 hour difference.

Comment: This code works perfectly on mi side. However, the following doesn't work:  echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s i', 1339599599).'<br>';//13-06-2012 15:06:59 59  echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s i', 1339599600).'<br>';//13-06-2012 16:06:00 00

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue, after checking the system side, I found that there is a difference between the **system time** and the time provided by the **stat** command that shows the last modified time.

```
-bash$ date;touch test;stat test;date
Sat Aug 22 08:06:35 BRT 2015
  File: `test'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 1          IO Block: 32768  regular empty file
Device: 13h/19d Inode: 25189989    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (/)   Gid: (/)
Access: 2015-08-22 08:07:29.968227010 -0300
Modify: 2015-08-22 08:07:29.968227064 -0300
Change: 2015-08-22 08:07:29.968238305 -0300
Sat Aug 22 08:06:35 BRT 2015
```

The difference in my case is 53sec.

Other machines I tested didn't show this difference.

Tested on a hosting machine.